# Android Game Programming - Sprite Collision

Tags: android, sprite, collision

I'm trying to detect if one of my Object's thezombiesprite in zombieSpriteList is colliding with my theplayersprite Object. I tried it with following code, but my game crashes at start...

```
public void checkForCollision(){
                for (int i = 0; i<zombieSpriteList.size(); i++){
                    ZombieSprite thezombiesprite = zombieSpriteList.get(i);
                       Rect mySprite = thezombiesprite.getBounds(); //create rect for every sprite in array

                            Rect myOtherSprite = theplayersprite.getBounds();
                              if(mySprite.intersect(myOtherSprite)){ //check if they touch
                                collision = true;
                         }

                  }
              }
```

In class ZombieSprite & PlayerSprite:

```
public Rect getBounds(){
           return new Rect(x, y, x+width, y+height);
         }
```

Comment: It crashes without error?

Comment: You'll need to post your LogCat output for us to help you.